# Using Ramda, how do you compose against binary functions?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

Ramda provides a case-sensitive equals with `R.equals`, however I want a case-insensitive equality test. Ramda also provides `R.compose`, but in the Ramda composition, it's assumed the left most argument is unary.

What I want to do is something like

```
R.compose( R.equals(...), R.toLower )
```

But, I want to compose the `R.toLower` on the binary function `R.equals`?

Is there a method to accomplish this? Types likes

```
(b->b->c) -> (a->b) => (a->a->c)
```

What I want is something like Haskell's [`Data.Function.on`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/Data.Function.html#on) which is defined as

> `on b u x y` runs the binary function b on the results of applying unary function `u` to two arguments `x` and `y`. From the opposite perspective, it transforms two inputs and combines the outputs.

Comment: You lost me at Ramda.

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT:** `R.useWith` comes very close to what you're looking for:

> Accepts a function fn and a list of transformer functions and returns a new curried function. When the new function is invoked, it calls the function fn with parameters consisting of the result of calling each supplied handler on successive arguments to the new function.

So you can define your function like this:

```
const equalsi = R.useWith(R.equals, [R.toLower, R.toLower]);
```

Example:

```js
const equalsi = R.useWith(R.equals, [R.toLower, R.toLower]);

const check = (a, b) => console.log(`${a} = ${b}?`, equalsi(a, b));

check('aaa', 'aaa');
check('aaa', 'aa');
check('aAa', 'aaa');
check('aaa', 'aAa');
check('aba', 'aaa');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

If you wanted something equivalent to the Haskell `on` function that you mention, you could define one as follows:

```js
const on = (b, u) => R.useWith(b, [u, u]);
const equalsi = on(R.equals, R.toLower);

const check = (a, b) => console.log(`${a} = ${b}?`, equalsi(a, b));

check('aaa', 'aaa');
check('aaa', 'aa');
check('aAa', 'aaa');
check('aaa', 'aAa');
check('aba', 'aaa');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

---

*Previous answer*:

There may be a more elegant way to do this, but this works:

```
const equalsi = R.unapply(R.compose(
    R.apply(R.equals),
    R.map(R.toLower)
));
```

Breaking it down:

```
// [] -> Boolean
// Takes an array of two strings and returns true if they are equal
R.apply(R.equals)

// [] -> Boolean
// Takes an array of two strings, converts them to lowercase, and returns true
// if those lowercase strings are equal
R.compose(R.apply(R.equals), R.map(R.toLower))

// String -> String -> Boolean
// Takes two strings, converts them to lowercase, and returns true if those lowercase
// string are equal
R.unapply(R.compose(R.apply(R.equals), R.map(R.toLower)));
```

You could also define your `on` function in terms of Ramda functions and then use that:

```
const on = (b, u) => R.unapply(R.compose(R.apply(b), R.map(u));

const equalsi = on(R.equals, R.toLower);
```

Comment: ahh, clever! (upvoted) I'll accept it in a week if this is the best answer. This isn't exactly desirable because I think you're losing a lot of typing with apply/unapply, and it's really ugly. But still clever.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Thanks! I found a much better approach using `useWith`. Please see my edit above.

Comment: I've been saying for ages that [`useWith`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#useWith) is a more Ramda-specific function, and not particularly tied to other FP tools.  TIL that it is closely related to Haskell's [`Data.Function.on`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/Data.Function.html#on).  Very nice!  However, the answer from @customcommander, using [`eqBy`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#eqBy), is still a better fit.

Answer (score 4):

There is also [`eqBy`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#eqBy) that you may want to consider:

> Takes a function and two values in its domain and returns true if the values map to the same value in the codomain; false otherwise.

```
R.eqBy(R.toLower, 'a', 'A'); //=> true
```

Example:

```js
console.log(R.eqBy(R.toLower, 'a', 'A'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, this is precisely the type of problem `eqBy` is designed to solve.